# Currency Conversion code isn't working - how to compare strings

Tags: c, string, input, comparison, currency

I'm making a simple currency converter, converting from Swedish SEK to European EUR or American USD.
When it should be printing out the conversion, the program just terminates instead. Visual Studio Code says there are no problems with the code so I don't understand the reason for this.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    float SEK;
    const float EUR = 0.0920;
    const float USD = 0.1000;
    const float YEN = 10.7600;
    char currency [256];

    printf("Enter amount of money you want to convert in SEK: ");
    scanf("%f", &SEK);
    printf("Enter the desired currency to convert to: ");
    scanf(" %c", &currency);

    if (currency == "EUR") {
        printf("\nFor %.4f SEK, you get: %.4f EUR", SEK, SEK*EUR);
    }
    else if (currency == "USD") {
        printf("\nFor %.4f SEK, you get: %.4f USD", SEK, SEK*USD);
    }
    getchar();
    getchar(); //used to give me a proper end on output of my program
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String comparison in C uses the strcmp() function. You can't do it with

```
 if (currency == "USD")
```

Add `#include <string.h>` and then

```
 if (strcmp (currency, "USD") == 0)
```

Also note that not testing the return value from scanf is *always a bug*. You think you can assume input is well-formed, but especially user input is often not.

Next, to read a string you can't use `%c`, but must use `%s`. Don't do it blindly, there are a lot of questions on SO how to limit the size of input as not to overflow your currency[] array. Search for them. If it mentions fgets(), take a closer look.

You should also get into the habit of writing your newlines `\n` at the *end* of a string, because that's when line-buffered output is flushed ("appears"). Windows is kind of broken in always appending a newline when a program ends, which leads to this frequently seen abomination of `printf ("\nwhatever")`.

Comment: Yes. There's another error where OP tries to scan a string with `%c`.

Comment: @MOehm Right, but I don't want to steal your rep. Make it another answer and you have my upvote.

Comment: @Jens I was about to post a full answer, just do it and you have my upvote :D

Comment: Rep, shmep. I was just going for a coffee and hoped you would do the write up for me. `:)` (That also has the advantage of a single useful answer.)

Comment: @Jens I don't think that would be stealing. Seems M Oehm gave you the tip so that the answer could be more complete, i.e. 1 answer holding all info.

Comment: Ok, I'll go for it. Stay healthy, people!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main issues in this code:

1. When using scanf you're waiting for a `char *` input, but %c is accepting `char`. 
   Change it to %s.
2. C doesn't allow string comparison with '==' operator. You should use strcmp() instead.